# google api certificate verification issue

Tags: google-api, gsutil

I have installed gsutil python package on several machines. And I never had any issue.
But recently on one machine I am getting certificate verification failed message.

```
Failure: Host accounts.google.com returned an invalid certificate (_ssl.c:491: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed): 
To learn more, see http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/general.html#rpcssl.
```

I have read the docs but could not figure it out how to solve this issue.